# Sign for inner multiplication of differential forms in math mode

Tags: math-mode

How can I typeset the following symbol on the lefthandside in mathmode?

[image]

I used `\lrcorner` which is too small.

Comment: Do you mean `\wedge`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `stix` fonts have `\intprod` for this symbol, corresponding to U+2A3C and printing like ⨼

It's not really difficult to build such a geometric shape anyway.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\intprod}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\int@prod{(0.1,0)(0.9,0)(0.9,0.8)}}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\intprodr}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\int@prod{(0.1,0.8)(0.1,0)(0.9,0)}}}

\newcommand{\int@prod}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1+$}%
  \setlength\unitlength{\wd\z@}%
  \begin{picture}(1,1)
  \roundcap
  \polyline#2
  \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$v\intprod \omega=i_{v}\omega$

$v\intprodr \omega=\omega i_{v}$

$A_{v\intprod \omega}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can you make the symbol thicker?

Comment: @Akerbeltz You can add `\linethickness{<dimen>}` inside the `picture` environment; experiment with thicknesses, maybe starting from `\linethickness{0.5pt}`.

Answer (score 2):

If `\lrcorner` is too small, why don't simply resize it?

I've used `\scalebox` from `graphicx` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\intprodl}{%
    \mathbin{\scalebox{1.5}{$\lrcorner$}}%
}
\newcommand{\intprodr}{%
    \mathbin{\scalebox{1.5}{$\llcorner$}}%
}
\begin{document}
    $v\intprodl \omega=i_{v}\omega$

    $v\intprodr \omega=\omega i_{v}$

    $A_{v\intprodl \omega}$

    $A_{v\intprodr \omega}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The usual symbol for the inner product of differential forms is the `\wedge` (∧) symbol

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

$v \wedge \omega = i_{\omega} \omega$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am following the book smooth manifolds by lee and on p. 358 he introduces this interior multiplication which is different from the wedge product. It is just plugging in the vector v in the first slot of the alternating tensor omega.

Comment: @TheGeekGreek: You wrote `inner product` and not `interior multiplication` in your title, that's why I thought about `wedge product`